# Code generator with Laravel

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

I am using Laravel 4 and I am looking for a system to generate simple short alphanumeric  codes, kinda like what Steam does when you login from a new machine, they send you an email with some text like this:

> Someone has tried to log in into your account from an unknown device.
>   If this is really you, please input this code to authenticate the
>   access:
>
> ### ZT27K
>
> Thank you

Is there some sort of random, short codes generator in Laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup! A bit down on the [helpers documentation page](http://laravel.com/docs/helpers) is the `str_random()` function, which can be used anywhere like so:

```
$string = str_random(5);
```

(Note: it defaults to 16 if its length argument is left out.)

Comment: Any information of what characters it uses? I am interested only in alphanumerics.

Comment: Yeah, it's alphanumeric, as per the source here: http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Support.Str.html#176-197. (The method is called ``random()``, not ``str_random()`` in the class. Notice that it falls back on ``quick_random()`` for older PHP versions, which takes its characters from ``0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ``.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I implemented mine, though`Str::random($length)` would be better:

```
 /**
     * @param string  prefix  Any desired  character to prepend on the generated code
     * @param int length a number indicating the number of characters in the code
     * @param string factor a string of characters to be mixed to generate the code
     * @return string string with  random characters based the provided length
     */
function  generateCode($prefix = '', $length = 8, $factor = null)
        {
$s  = "9/A/B/0/C/2/D/E/3/F/G/H/I//J/4/K/L/M/N/O/5/P/7/R/S/8/T/U/V/6/W/X/Y/Z";
            if ($factor  === null)
                $factor = $s;
  $rdm_text_arr  =  explode("/", $factor, strlen($factor));
            $code_array  = array();
            array_push($code_array, $prefix);

            for ($i = 1; $i <= $length; $i++) :
                array_push($code_array, $rdm_text_arr[mt_rand(0, count($rdm_text_arr) - 1)]);
            endfor;

            return implode("", $code_array);
        }
```

and this is a sample output: `WJH3Z0MX`

You may also try `Str::random(8)` which gives 8 random characters.